# Update [Closed On} When Status = Closed

Tags: list, custom-list, calculated-column

I am wanted to add similar functionality to the "Created On" Date column for my "Closed On" column. I want the date to automatically populate once I change status from Active or Pending to Closed, and want it to show once I save an item with this status change. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create calculated column **Closed On** with below formula:

```
=IF(Status="Closed",Modified,"")
```

Select `Date and Time` as data type for calculated column.

[image]

Comment: Would this not create a new closed date anytime the item is modified after close?

Comment: You should go with what Erin L has suggested. Because if item get modified, then closed date will also get modified if you use calculated column.

Answer (score 2):

Use a SharePoint Designer workflow, started when the item is created, to wait for the item to be closed.

`Wait for Status to equal Closed`
`Set Closed On to Today`

You shouldn't use a calculated column, nor a workflow with an if statement, as some are suggesting. If the item is opened in edit mode any time after it's closed, and then saved (even if there are no changes) your Closed On value would change.

Comment: Hi Erin,  I wanted to know even for the workflow it will get changed if it starts with if condition and user select " start workflow automatically when an item is changed" option. I know calculated column isn't good option.

Comment: If you start a workflow every time an item is changed, and use `if status = closed` then yes, it will change every time is saved as long as the status is closed. That's why you should use a `wait for` with run on start.

Comment: But why would user will start the workflow manually? but yes for best result "wait for" is better. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: Or add an "if Closed On is Not Empty then exit" condition in the Workflow approach

Comment: Don't have them start it manually. Check the run when item is created checkbox.